# Pandas DataFrame from List of DataFrames: ValueError: Must pass 2d input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The simplest reproduction of the error:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 5))
b = pd.DataFrame(range(6, 10))
res = pd.DataFrame([a, b])
print(res)
```

When I run the above code I get: `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 4, 1)`

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are already dataframes, you are probably looking  for `concat(axis=1)`:

```
res = pd.concat([a, b],axis=1)
```

---

```
   0  0
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  3  8
3  4  9
```

`axis=1` means you'll be concatenating a,b column wise and not row wise